# How do I rename an entire project in VC++ 2005

Tags: visual-c++

I've got a really large project I made for myself and rece3ntly a client asked for their own version of it with some modifications.  The project name was rather silly and my client wants the source so I figured it'd be best if I renamed all my files from

```
sillyname.h
sillyname.cpp
sillyname.dsp
```

etc..
Unfortunatly after I added everything back together I can't see any way to change the project name itself.  Plus now I'm getting this error on compilation.

```
main.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __imp__InitCommonControls@0
Debug/New_Name_Thats_not_so_silly.exe : fatal error LNK1120: 1 unresolved externals
Error executing link.exe.
```

There has to be an easier way to change all this, right?

Comment: Alright It actually compiles fine just the Debug Version doesn't... Strange.

Comment: This comment is in response to "where is solution explorer?"   Here are some images of where it is:  http://images.google.com/images?um=1&hl=en&q=%22visual+studio%22+%22solution+explorer%22&btnG=Search+Images

Comment: If only the debug version is bad, then did you try a CLEAN, then rebuild?  just one more idea.  apologies if you already tried that. :)

Answer (score 3):

Here is a [Step by Step](http://www.platinumbay.com/blogs/dotneticated/archive/2008/01/01/renaming-and-copying-projects-and-solutions.aspx) on Steve Andrews' blog (he works on Visual Studio at Microsoft)

Comment: "When you rename a project, most likely you will want to rename the output assembly and/or the root namespace for the project. To do this, right-click on the project node and choose Properties. You can also double-click on the Properties (C#) or My Project (VB) node. "
Where is Solution Explorer?

Comment: This comment is in response to "where is solution explorer?"  maybe a google image search will turn up some helpful screenshot that is recognizable:  http://images.google.com/images?um=1&hl=en&q=%22visual+studio%22+%22solution+explorer%22&btnG=Search+Images

Comment: If it's not already on screen (looking like que's link) try the menu item "View | Solution Explorer" OR type Ctrl+Alt+L

Answer (score 1):

I haven't verified this, but I've done this a number of times and if my memory serves me right, you can actually use the search-and-replace functionality in VS2005 to rename all instances of the string "X" to "Y" in any type of file.
Then you need to close the solution and change the project (and any other file with the same name regardless of extension) file name(s).

You will obviously need to do a full rebuild afterwards.

Comment: Actually this is what I did initially.  The worst part is I just found a tool that does this and I'm still getting the same error on compile.. grr

Answer (score 1):

I find it always annoying too, to do this manually.

So I tried some tools available by googling- two didn't work (VS C++ here), dunno, if they are more useful for C#.

The following tool worked good for me: I have used the trial version, but I will pay 39,- bucks for it. For me it is worth it. It has also a VS add-in. VS 2013 was not supported directly, at least not mentioned, yet, when I looked:
http://www.kinook.com/CopyWiz

In-place rename didn't work (access error), but "rename-while-copying" worked fine.

But I really wonder, if it is so difficult as some programmers claim. For most parts file renaming and a search&replace of all occurences in all text files in the project dir should be a quite easy and working approach. Maybe someone can contibute what shall be so difficult.

The rational part of my brain forbids the dreaming part to program an own tool- I am lucky ! :-)

Answer (score 0):

You can simply rename the .vcproj or .dsp file and then either create a new workspace (sln dsw) and include the renamed project or simply chnage the name inside the sln file (it's just xml) I can't remember the format of the old workspace but it's still text.

You can either manually rename and reinclude all the .cpp of edit the project file and rename them in there.

sorry don't know of  refactoring tool that will do all this but there probably is one.

Answer (score 0):

I assume that in addition to the renamed set of files, you also still maintain a complete "parallel" set of the original files in some other directory, am I right?

Assuming you have both versions, what I would do is:

Get a file comparison tool like [Beyond Compare](http://www.google.com/search?hl=en&q=%22beyond+compare%22+%22scooter+software%22&btnG=Search) or [DiffMerge](http://www.google.com/search?hl=en&q=sourcegear+diffmerge&btnG=Search) and compare the old SLN file and the new SLN file side-by-side.  Also do this for each "proj" file and any other "config" type files.

It is possible to edit these files by hand.  Usually looking at what is different between two copies will help illuminate what you should do to get the second one working.

You might as well start tinkering with the renamed project by hand, anyway, given that it already isn't working.  You can't make it much worse.  And: you might learn some handy tricks about the XML structure of these files.

Even if you do make small mistakes when hand-tweaking this files, I have repeatedly been very impressed by how Visual Studio handles things.  Visual Studio will usually tell you exactly where you got it wrong.